# How do you call functions with __P in the prototype?

Tags: c, header-files

I have been going through some header files and see that there are many function prototype like this:

```
returntype some_name __P(arguments);
```

If I were to call this function how do I do it? Do I use something like

```
some_name(arguments);
```

excluding the `__P`, or is there some other way to call such functions?

Comment: Could you link the header file that includes that so we could take a look at it?

Comment: Where have you found such declarations? Can you show one? It probably is a macro expanding to something.

Comment: This is the link to the header file [Link](web.mit.edu/~jik/sipbsrc/i386_nbsd1/webster/src/server/dbm/PORT/sys/db.h/) It has something like void  __dbpanic __P((DB *dbp)); how do I call __dbapanic? Just __dapanic(*dbp) or in some other way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of prototype uses a macro `__P` to allow inclusion and compilation on very old systems that do not support C90 prototypes (aka *ansi prototypes*).

On most systems, the argument to the `__P` macro expands to the argument list, as illustrated below:

```
#ifdef __USING_STONE_AGE_COMPILER__
#define __P(args)  ()
#else
#define __P(args)  args

int some_name __P((int argc, char *argv[]));
```

On obsolete systems, the above declaration expands to `int some_name();` whereas it expands to the full prototype otherwise: `int some_name(int argc, char *argv[]);`

Just ignore the `__P` macro and use `some_name(arguments);` syntax to call the function. Also note that the macro name `__P` is not significant, the author of the package could have used any name for this purpose.

Comment: So this is some stone-age legacy? Interesting what effort ppl make just to avoid porting code to mideval C at least ...

Comment: @Olaf Usually the people who are avoiding are not the same who are making the effort.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Maybe for commercial libs. But then, a customer still using such (or even bying new) should think thrice, as such legacies often hide deeper issues (like bad maintenance). Such hacks are often added to (libs or usier code) if the original developer is not available anymore and no one really understands the code.

Comment: @Olaf: I agree.  It probably indicates that the header itself is very old.  Very old compilers for obsolete targets are still used for maintenance purposes.  But even for this purpose, using an external tool to remove or rewrite some of the newer constructs would be a better option.

Comment: If that is a header for some product library, that's scary.  It's nastier than comments imply - declaring a function as `func()` produces wildly different results from declaring it as `func( type1 arg1, type2 arg2, type3 arg3 )`.  If the declaration doesn't match the actual definition of the code (supposedly in the compiled library), the results of calling that function would be undefined behavior.  If the header is distributed **by someone who knows what they're doing** with compiled libraries, the *only* possible declarations in the header would match the actual delivered implementation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: you are correct for modern systems, but pre-ansi compilers used simpler ABIs for which this problem was less pressing. Nevertheless, calling `lseek(fd, 0, 0);` instead of `lseek(fd, 0L, 0);` did invoke undefined behavior.